# Error while DeSerializing XML with namespaces to C# Object

Tags: c#

I have an XML file which starts something like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Deal xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DealioCapLinkLib.Dealio.Models" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <AccountingDate>2019-09-30</AccountingDate>
```

When I try to convert this object to XML like below, I get an error:-

```
 private static void Prod_Error_Test()
 {
            string prodRequestXml = File.ReadAllText("ProdXml.xml");

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Service.Deal));
            Service.Deal request ;

           var reader = new StringReader(prodRequestXml);
           request = (Service.Deal)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

 }
```

The Error Message is `"There is an error in XML document (2, 2).".` The Inner Exception Message is `"<Deal xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DealioCapLinkLib.Dealio.Models'> was not expected."`

Service.Deal is a WCF Proxy.So I may not be able to add any attributes. Can anyone suggest what to do here ?

Comment: try adding the XmlRootAttribute to the serializer`var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Service.Deal), new XmlRootAttribute("Deal");`

Answer (score 0):

Being a WCF proxy doesn't preclude adding attributes; in particular, it is usually a `partial class`, which means you can have your own **separate** file, with:

```cs
namespace Service
{
    [XmlRoot("Deal", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DealioCapLinkLib.Dealio.Models")]
    partial class Deal {}
}
```

But ultimately: if the type doesn't conveniently fit the XML: *stop fighting it* - create a new *separate* type that fits the XML and works well with `XmlSerializer`, and then map between the two types in your own code.